# web.config explanation of profile properties

Tags: properties, web-config, profile

I have a List<> as part of a users profile stroed in the web.config like so

```
<properties>
        <clear/>
        <add name="EditorUploads"
         type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String]]"/>
      </properties>
```

Although this code works, I don't know why. I can't find any documentation on what the **`1** means anywhere. Can anyone shed some light on this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ``1` is a different notation used for generic types.

The `1` indicates the number of generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this notation when writing stacktraces as strings as well. It seems to indicate the generic characters <> and the following type is the generic type, eg:

```
List<string>
```

Answer (score 0):

To denote the number of Type parameters that follow.